# How to squeeze text into a shape

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I'm trying to squeeze a text into a shape so that after removing the shape the text gives the impression of the shape. In the above example MYTEXT should go into the elipse.

How can i do this with inkscape ?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Save your work. Experiment first :-)
- Path Menu > *Object to path* - Convert the text to a path
- Path Menu > *Path Effect Editor* - Shows path effect editor at right
- Choose *Envelope Deformation* from drop down
- Click the *Add* button
- Select the *Top bend path* option (edit on canvas button - the left of the four btns on each row)
- Shift-drag out the tangents from the left and right node
- Repeat for the *bottom bend*
- For the *left and right bends* - optionally just move the upper and lower nodes closer together to pinch the left and right tips, but enure they stay vertically aligned

TIP - if you don't want the text to go right into the tips of the corners, add a '+' to the beginning and the end of the text and then when you're done, paint these characters white or transparent. This is because when you convert text to a path, it will ignore any leading or terminating spaces because they're not part of the 'path'

EDIT - additional example
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, i can make it this way. Thank you. But for me it is a little bit too much free-handy and it does'nt shows up "perfect", too much deformation than "resize" of the letters ...

Comment: It would be perfect if the letter strokes would be bend outside and not inside, getting an amplifier effect ...

Comment: You can sort of get closer to that by making the points on the top edge closer to each other and the same with the bottom edge, so that you squeeze the top and the bottom while keeping the middle constant. - I added an example image above

Comment: Thank you. But it is all too much deformation. I'm looking more a "DuPont" style ( http://www.autoevolution.com/images/news/dupont-extends-jeff-gordon-sponsorship-25861_1.jpg )

Comment: Maybe this video will help: http://screencasters.heathenx.org/wp-content/videos/ep060/ep060.html

Comment: I love inkscape, but this is one area that it's weak in. For path envelopes, AI is still better at it.

Comment: @DAO1 What stands "AI" for ?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator